# Limit definition of derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives

[image: Question]

How do I go about doing this question? Am i using the right formula?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with @Jacobs correction
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

substitute $x=2$

$$f'(2) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}$$

substitute the definition of $f$, noting that $f(2)=2$ and $f(2+h) = \frac{2+h}{3-(2+h)}$:

$$f'(2) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{(2+h)}{3-(2+h)}-2}{h}$$

now simplify the double fraction in the limit.

HINT: $h$ will be simplified away in this case and the term in the limit will be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula's not quite right. You want: $$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

It's kind of confusing to use $\Delta x$ here, since it's important not to mix it up with $x$. The notation I learned is: $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: I understand that thanks, but how do i proceed from there on to finish the question? Completely lost right now =/